# Microsoft Fix It

Tags: windows

Is using **Microsoft Fix It** a good idea or does it generally cause more problems than it fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it will cause problems. Contrarily, it becomes useful sometimes.

For example, my nephew told me the Recycle Bin and Internet Explorer icons are missing on his desktop. I checked the "Customize Desktop" settings, and the icons were also missing in there (he probably messed with the registry). So I used Fix It and it quickly restored the icons.

Check out [this page](https://fixit.support.microsoft.com/reporting/) for some info on what Fix It solutions are used by Microsoft products users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will harm your PC. Most of these Auto fix software only find and fix basic problems. I just scanned my PC (which I know has a bad CD-ROM) and it told me to check the power. Not entirely accurate because the green light is on but it could tell it wasn't working..

Answer (score 0):

I used it once to fix a user's Internet explorer where the menu bar would not appear unless they pressed Alt.  Worked great.  Your mileage may vary.